# When do we need U(n+2) to solve a problem that can be formulated in U(n)?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, homotopy-type-theory

I understand the need for a universe hierarchy, and that each new level brings additionnal proof-theoretic strength.

In the HoTT book there are examples of proofs that need to use the next level in the Universe hierarchy.

Do we have examples of inhabited types A:U(n), where the construction of the inhabitants/proof a:A requires the use of U(n+2) ?

Comment: Presumably, you could formulate a syntactic theory of HoTT restricted to some fixed number of universes inside of (full) HoTT. The consistency proof should then require at least that number of actual universes.

Comment: I'm no expert on these matters, but I'm of the impression that higher universes can also be used to define faster-growing functions from the naturals to the naturals. So you could define $A$ to be the type of all functions having so-and-so growth behaviour, and then give an inhabitant of $A$ by employing higher universes. I can't say how to formalize this properly.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/is-church-pentation-implementable-in-agda) on the theoretical CS stack exchange asks if pentation is implementable on Church numerals in a predicative variant of System F. In the normal, impredicative system, this is quite easy, because we have:

```
ℕ : Type
ℕ = forall (R : Type). (R -> R) -> (R -> R)

1 : ℕ
1 R s z = s z

hyper : (ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ) -> (ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ)
hyper op m n = n ℕ (op m) 1
```

So, because a Church numeral can be instantiated to work on the type of Church numerals, we can easily iterate an operation to get to the next hyper operation.

However, in a predicative system, the quantification over types increases the size of the quantifying type to be larger than the size of the types quantified over. So, a Church numeral that can be instantiated to operate on Church numerals must be one that quantifies over a higher universe.

The person asking the question links to a paper on the functions representable in such a stratified system with $\omega$ universe levels (I.E. one for each natural number). The paper shows that the representable functions are the super-elementary functions, which includes tetration, particular *finite* compositions of tetration, and products and sums of those functions. However, the only reason that all these functions are even representable is that they make use of Church numerals for *all* universes. So, for instance, tetration has a type (something) like:

```
_^^_ : Church 0 -> Church 1 -> Church 0
```

That is, to compute tetration for 0-level numerals, you must make use of higher level numerals. And depending on the complexity of the function, you may have to use much higher levels to compute 0-level numerals (arbitrarily high levels).

I showed in the answer there how if you add even more universes, it is possible to give a uniform type for tetration, which then means pentation can be defined. But now the universes involved are indexed by *transfinite* ordinals (if at all), and you still (seem to) need to go up levels to define some functions on lower (but still very high) levels.